# Авторизация пользователя на php/mysql/session

Tags: php, mysql, сессия

Делаю авторизацию, возникла такая проблема. При нажатии на `<a href="logout.php"> Logout </a>` ,  происходит редирект на **login.php**, т.е. на форму, но если в соседней вкладке зайти на **home.php**, то редирект не происходит и пользователь как бы остаётся в системе. Т.е. не происходит разрушение сессии.

Вот код php:

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {     
include("config.php");


$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

$_SESSION['login_user']=$username;

$query = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM login WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'");

 if (mysql_num_rows($query) != 0)
{

 echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'> location.href='home.php' </script>";   
  }

  else
  {
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('User Name Or Password Invalid!')</script>";
}

}

?>
```

home.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>    
<h1>Welcome 
<?php 
session_start();
$login_session=$_SESSION['login_user'];
echo $login_session;?> </h1>
<a href="logout.php"> Logout </a>
</body>
</html>
```

logout.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(session_destroy())
{
header("Location: login.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Ну потому что, нет проверки на сессию, ты пускаешь пользователя вне зависимости, авторизован он или нет.

Comment: Сделал проверку if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) { unset($_SESSION['login_user']); header("Location: login.php"); } но не работает

Comment: @Beginner, так вы же удаляете сессию если она есть.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, я уже не помню всех тонкостей с сессиями, но в моем видении это так: при **логине** создаешь некий ключ в сессии, например:

```
//login.php
if (mysql_num_rows($query) != 0){
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)
    $user_login = $row['username'];
    $_SESSION['user_login'] = $user_login;//присваиваем нашему ключу значение
//В нашем случае, логин юзера
    if(isset($_GET['requested_url']){
        header('Location: '.urldecode($_GET['requested_url']));
    }//Если был задан запрашиваемый адрес, то автоматически перенаправляем его туда.
}
```

Потом, когда к тебе на страницу заходят, первым делом вызываешь скрипт, который проверяет сессию:

```
//somepage.php
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_login']){
    header('Location: login.php?requested_url='.urlencode($_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]));//В идеале, передавая и адрес страницы, на которую изначально хотел зайти пользователь, чтобы потом сразу перенаправить его туда.
}
require_once('content.php');

//logout.php
session_unset();
header('Location: login.php');
```

Сразу, просьба исключить комментарии про голый mysql вместо PDO и иже с ним, ответ ориентируется на достижение других целей.

Answer (score 1):

Я использую сессии и авторизацию через $_SERVER, но может вам пригодится следующее:

```
session_unset ();
session_destroy ();
$connection->close();
unset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'], $_SERVER);
header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй использовать `unset($_SESSION['login_user']);`

`session_destroy()` не желательно использовать

Используй проверки `if(isset($_SESSION['login_user']))` ...

Comment: Написал if(isset($_SESSION['login_user']))
{
unset($_SESSION['login_user']);  
header("Location: login.php");
} и всё равно...